# Waiting until a callback is executed

Tags: javascript, callback, wait

I want to wait until a callback is finished. I tried something like:

```
let wait = true;
setTimeout(() => {
    console.log("wait = false");
    wait = false;
}, 2000);
console.log("waiting");
while(true) {
    if(!wait) break;
}
console.log("finished waiting");
```

The only output is

```
waiting
```

And it doesn't proceed further. Even "wait = false" is not printed after 2 seconds. Can someone explain why this is happening?

Comment: your `while` loop will never run `setTimeout` to run. it's a synchronous logic and will block the js thread till eternity.

Comment: I imagine it doesn't work because you're blocking the browser with an infinite loop.  Why do you think you need to *wait*?  Why can't you just perform the next task from within the callback?  It seems like you're trying to solve the wrong problem here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your `while` loop will never let `setTimeout` run. it's a *synchronous* infinite loop logic and will block the js thread till eternity.

`setTimeout` is an asynchronous method and registers itself in event queue. When the main stack is done with it's work, event loop checks the queue for pending work and brings it back in main thread.

In your case, main stack will never be free, because `while` loop will never complete.

You can use `Promise` to do that.

```js
var promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('timeout executed after 2s');
      resolve(); // resolve when setTimeout is done.
    }, 2000);
});
console.log('waiting');
promise.then(_ => console.log("finished waiting")); // Use `.then` to do work after promise is resolved.
```

Or you can do that just inside the callback of `setTimeout`

```js
var callback = function() { 
  console.log('finished execution');
  // all other work.
}

console.log('waiting');
setTimeout(callback, 2000);
```

Or use `async-await`. This gives the impression that the logic is synchronous by waiting for promise to resolve before moving ahead.

```js
(async function() {
  console.log('waiting')
  await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(_ => {
      console.log('setTimeout executed');
      resolve();
    }, 2000)
  })
  console.log('finished execution')
})()
```